# Excel: How do I copy and paste ranges into different cells/worksheets based on the real world date?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number worksheets `Current Standing`, `2022`, `2023`, `2024` etc

`Current standing` is just a single range `D12:D35` and `2022/3/4` look like this:

[image]

I'm trying to copy the range `D12:D35` from `Current Standing` to the current month & year. Current month and year being the literal current real world date.

**If I ran the script today it should:**

1. Copy `D12:D35` from `Current Standing`
2. Paste it into `D3/April` in the `2022` worksheet.

**If I run the script in 3 months (July):**

1. Copy `D12:D35` from `Current standing`
2. Paste it into `G3/July` in the 2022 worksheet.

**If I run the script in 12 months (April, 2023):**

1. Copy `D12:D35` from `Current standing`
2. Paste it into `D3/April` in the 2023 worksheet.

I've managed to figure out how to copy and paste with vba, while protecting and unprotecting the sheet but I'm not sure how I'd take account of the month and year requirement.

```
Option Explicit
Sub update()

If Worksheets("Current Standing").ProtectContents = True Then

Worksheets("Current Standing").Unprotect
Range("D12:D35").Copy
Range("F12:F35").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Current Standing").Protect

Else

Range("D12:D35").Copy
Range("F12:F35").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("F12:F35").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Current Standing").Protect

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Year(Date)` will give you today's year, similarly `Month(Date)` and `Day(Date)` From that you should be able to get to the sheet and range you want

Comment: Maybe : `Sheets("Current Standing").Range("D12:D35").Copy: Sheets(CStr(Year(Date))).Cells(3, Month(Date)).PasteSpecial (xlValues)`

Comment: That works perfectly @karma is there an easy way to offset the rows? I figured out 3 controls the columns. But my real table starts on column G rather than A

Comment: mak47, Yes, my code assumed that month January will start at column A (column number 1). If it starts on column G .... (not tested yaaa...) try to add 6 for the `month(date)`. So it become like this : `Sheets("Current Standing").Range("D12:D35").Copy: Sheets(CStr(Year(Date))).Cells(3, Month(Date) + 6).PasteSpecial (xlValues)`. For example, month(date) result is 2 (February). If you don't add 6, it will place on column B (column number 2). If you add 6, itu will put on column H (column 8). Again, this is not tested.